# Partitioning the plane into subsets with restricted number of intersection with lines

Tags: discrete-geometry

Suppose there are $n$ points in the plane. So there are $O(n^2)$ lines generating by these points. I would like to partition the plane into some subsets such that each subset of points intersected by a few number of lines. I was wondering if there is any theorem about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the type of result you seek? Partition the plane into triangles none of
which meet too many of the given lines.
More precisely,

> In this paper we consider the following problem: Given a set ℒ of $n$ lines in the plane, partition the plane into $O(r^2)$ triangles so that no triangle meets more than $O(n/r)$ lines of ℒ. We present a deterministic algorithm for this problem with $O(nr \log n \log^\omega r)$ running time, where $\omega$ is a constant $<3.33$.

Note above $n$ is the number of lines, whereas in your notation $n$ is the number of
points which determine up to $\binom{n}{2}$ lines.

> Agarwal, Pankaj K. "Partitioning arrangements of lines I: An efficient deterministic algorithm." *Discrete & Computational Geometry* 5.1 (1990): 449-483. ([Journal link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02187805).)

---

[image]

---